# Keycloak - enable email mapping or alias

Tags: email, oauth, single-sign-on, keycloak

We are using keycloak as auth provider by utilizing the OAuth Code Flow. The user logs in with their normal email and password on the keycloak login page. Is there a way to mask/hide or even map email adresses? Apple is doing this by saving the real email but using fake mails like j24hj21h4@apple.com for the "outer world". The reason I need this feature is to hide the real email adresses of our users for SSO.

Comment: At what point in the login flow do you want to hide email, is it when he types in his email id in the login screen or during the api call ? or when storing it in db ?

Comment: The best would be, that the alias email will be generated during registration and replaced during login. I don't want the real email to be part of the token but the fake mail. Nobody who "gets" the token should be aware of the real email.

Comment: Maybe you can use the fake-email as username. Than you can login with this "email" and you must build your token without the real email.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, your best bet would be extend the Authentication SPI of keycloak and implement your logic, it's is totally achievable.
This is not something you get out of keycloak by default, but it provides flexibility to plug our extensions.
Here you can find more details on this https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi

Answer (score 0):

When Keycloak creates the ID token for your end-user, the email claim inside the token is not mandatory. You could just omit the mail claim.

To do so, under `Clients` -> `YourClientName` -> `ClientScopes` -> `YourClientName-dedicated` remove the `email` scope.
That should do the trick.

You can verify under the evaluate tab under the clients' scopes overview.